# Bash scripting, cannot substitute a command line variable

Tags: json, bash

This is a small command line script that is used to post a json body in an http server. I am finding difficulties to pass the first command line argument $1 to the json body.

```
#!/bin/bash
curl  -X POST -d '{  "game": 16, "id": $(($1)) }' http://localhost:10000/
```

The command does not fail, however the http body contains exactly

> {  "game": 16, "id": $(($1)) }

I want to run the script ./script 123 and send the json body

```
{  "game": 16, "id": 3 }
```

How can I do this using bash?

Comment: Yes, everything is needed. It is going to be a number actually, eg 12345 so I need all chars

Comment: In general, you should not be creating JSON using string interpolation, because the contents of `$1` may need to be correctly escaped to produce valid JSON. Something like `$(jq --arg val "$1" '{game: 16, id: $val}')` is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using single quotes will print literal characters. You need to use double quotes for string interpolation. Try:

```
curl  -X POST -d "{  \"game\": 16, \"id\": $1 }" http://localhost:10000/
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use single quotes so you don't have to escape double quotes like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
curl  -X POST -d '{  "game": 16, "id": '$1' }' http://localhost:10000/
```